# How do I save as draft in strapi?

Tags: strapi

currently i've manage to post into strapi, but i cant set post status to draft. I am using graphql, and there is no post status in mutation. what I have to do?

thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way that I found to do that is just passing the property **published_at** as null when perform the mutation.

***published_at*** is a default property that strapi assign to each collection.

For the query

```
mutation CreateRecord (
  $recordName: String!,
  $published_at: DateTime
) {
  createComment (input: {
    data : {
      recordName: $recordName,
      published_at: $published_at
    }
  })
}
```

and when is time to send the values

```
createRecords({
  variables: {
    recordName: "I am a new record saved as draft"
    published_at: null
  }
});
```

Comment: Ok, and how to publish the draft posting, via API?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Strapi are you using?

The Draft & Publish feature has been released recently. You should definitely give it a try: https://strapi.io/blog/announcing-a-new-draft-and-publish-feature

Comment: i am using the latest version, i know that strapi have draft and publish feature, but i can only use it when using strapi admin area. in this case i want to post using my nuxt app with graphql mutation. but I cant found a way to accomplish it.